# Hardware video acceleration in chromium does not work

Tags: video, chromium

Installed chromium:

```
snap install chromium --channel=latest/candidate/hwacc
```

All Intel:

- CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-12400 (12) @ 4.400GHz
- GPU: Intel Alder Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730]

But hardware video acceleration never worked.
Checked with `intel_gpu_top` on youtube and google meet.
Thought it would be OTB. But for some reason it is not so.
Kubuntu 23.04 system.
Tried Ubuntu Live 23.04, same thing.
I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware acelerated video is working for me with Chromium Beta SNAP version 118.xxx.xxx with an intel GPU (UHD 620). It worked fine straight away without extra configuration as shown by intel_gpu_top. This worked on Ubuntu 23.04 and still works in Ubuntu 23.10. I think only the beta channel has hardware acceleration enabled for now. I also use Wayland sessison, which I think is needed also for hardware acceleration. Also check that VA-API is working using vainfo which should list all the codecs that can be used for hardware acceleration. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and useful answer.
I'm also using a Wayland session, albeit in Kubuntu.
Firefox supports hardware acceleration, but not chromium-beta.
It is not clear why so. I checked on vainfo, I don't see any problems.
Also checked crome://gpu. There is also accelerated.

Comment: @nteodosio, I tried. But this bug was reported, right? I confirmed it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1816497

Comment: Indeed, and just for closure, in that bug report it was confirmed that the asker was not on beta or edge channels, confirming that this answer is correct.